# ektorp couchDB to android replication

Tags: android, couchdb, httpclient, replication, ektorp

I am trying to synchronize my CouchDB with my android in a way that it works as good offline as online and as far as I understand the .continues(true/false) is the way to go for this. But is there some way to actually change it on runtime some way? I am thinking of having a BroadcastReciever listening to if there is any CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE and set the value of .continues() accordingly but I can't get it to work... any suggestions?

```
protected void startEktorp() {
    httpClient = new TouchDBHttpClient(server);
    dbInstance = new StdCouchDbInstance(httpClient);

    HamsterSyncEktorpAsyncTask startupTask = new HamsterSyncEktorpAsyncTask() {

        @Override
        protected void doInBackground() {
            // create a local database
            dbConnector = dbInstance.createConnector(DATABASE_NAME, true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSuccess() {
            // Create the query and get the results
            queryDB();
            // Start doing the replications!
            startReplications();
        }
    };
    startupTask.execute();
}

public synchronized void queryDB() {
    ViewQuery viewQuery = new ViewQuery()
            .designDocId("_design/" + dDocName).viewName(viewName)
            .reduce(false).includeDocs(true);
    ViewResult viewResult = dbConnector.queryView(viewQuery);
    Log.v("SUCCESS", viewResult.getRows().toString());

    notifyHandlers(viewResult);
}

/**
 * Replicates the database from server to the phone and vice versa.
 */
public void startReplications() {
    // pull this database to the test replication server
    pullCommand = new ReplicationCommand.Builder().source(DATABASE_PATH)
            .target(DATABASE_NAME).continuous(true).build();

    pushCommand = new ReplicationCommand.Builder().source(DATABASE_NAME)
            .target(DATABASE_PATH).continuous(true).build();

    HamsterSyncEktorpAsyncTask pushReplicaton = new HamsterSyncEktorpAsyncTask() {

        @Override
        protected void doInBackground() {
            dbInstance.replicate(pullCommand);
            ReplicationStatus status = dbInstance.replicate(pushCommand);
            Log.e(TAG, status.getSessionId().toString());
        }
    };
    pushReplicaton.execute();
}
```

I am also wondering if there are any way to know if and when the replication actually sent/got something new and update my listview in the app showing all the documents in my database (the queryDB() function)?

Comment: A few months ago I tried to get TouchDB working with Android only to realize some features were simply not implemented yet. I know Couchbase is focusing on getting mobile stuff going this year, but for the time being ... TouchDB for Android is not production ready from what I've read.